# How to find items in a ListView

Tags: flutter

I created a new Recipe form that presents users with a list of ~20 items to choose from by adding a numeric quantity to TextField in each Row. The ingredients are presented in an scrolling ListView. Each item(ingredient) is a Row that includes a TextField and a Text with the ingredient name.

I need to access items in a ListView.  I need to find items where the user has inputted data in the TextFields when the Save Button has been pushed. I'm new to Flutter and don't want to create a hack because I don't understand best practices.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your final layout?

Comment: ![create recipe](https://imgur.com/a/THL9OGV)

Answer (score 0):

First of make pojo class for your data to display on listview.

for example your listview containg list of userdata..

```
  Future<UserData> userDataList;
  // then check listview data value..
    userDataList.then((userData){
  if(userData.title=="OK") // here check user input data.
  print(userData.title);
});
```

UserData class is pojo class it conting getter setter methods...